# Subclipse label decorations not synchronizing

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I use the SpringSourceToolSuite (v2.9.2.201205071000-RELEASE) version of Eclipse along with Subclipse (v1.8.13). When checking in code I use Tortoise and then return to eclipse where I run a full project clean, which resets the subversion decorations (i.e asterisk, cross, question mark etc) to their correct status.

This is usually all I need to do, but lately the decorations do not get reset even though I have (say) just checked in the file and comparing with the repository shows no differences.

I can edit a file by adding and deleting a space and then the decorations reset correctly. This is proving to be a pain, and now I have a package which is decorated with a + sign and I can't get rid of it.

Anybody else getting this problem or managed to resolve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try: right click on project, Team-> Refresh/Cleanup

Comment: Team > Refresh/Cleanup synchronizes the state of the decorators and cache with current SVN information.  That should be the option that always works.

Comment: Oops, my mistake - I chose the wrong refresh. The team > refresh does work. Not sure why I am having to do this manually though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change {label_decoration} to {resource_url} in Preferences / Team / SVN / Label Decorations / Text Decorations / Project.

So my Project entry is: {outgoing_flag} {name} {revision} [{resource_url}{root_prefix}: {first_branchOrTag_child}]